# How do I know what the gain is of a second order system which is expressed in this format?

Tags: polynomials

Can someone please explain how to know the gain of a second order system which is expressed as such
$$\frac{number_{1}}{(s+ number_{2})(s+ number_{3})}$$
For example
$$\frac{40}{(s+0.2)(s+20)}$$
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard form of second order transfer function is ,

$$k\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}$$

where,
$k$ is the dc gain
$\zeta$ is the damping factor and
$\omega_n $ is the undamped natural frequency.

So first expand the denominator and try to make it of the standard form.

$$\frac{40}{(s+0.2)(s+20)} = \frac{40}{s^2+20.2s+4}$$

Could you find the gain now?

Comment: So if $$k\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}$$ is the standard form, and I have $$\frac{40}{s^2+20.2s+4}$$ , that means $\omega_n^2$ is 4, so that's like saying I have $$10\frac{4}{s^2+20.2s+4}$$. Therefore the gain, k, is 10. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep, you got it!